# Aggregate function with voting api / fivestar

Tags: rating

I'm using Drupal 7, [fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) and [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi).

I use hook_votingapi_results_alter to aggregate some results (number of votes above 80 (4 stars)) and use this in views.

I followed the api, but it does not work :

```
function MYMODULE_votingapi_results_alter(&$vote_results, $content_type, $content_id) {
  $sql  = "SELECT v.value_type, v.tag, COUNT(v.value) as count_4_stars ";
  $sql .= "FROM {votingapi_vote} v ";
  $sql .= "WHERE v.content_type = '%s' AND v.content_id = %d AND v.value_type = 'percent' AND v.value >= 80 ";
  $sql .= "GROUP BY v.value_type, v.tag";

  $aggregates = db_query($sql, $content_type, $content_id);

  while ($aggregate = db_fetch_array(aggregates)) {
    $vote_results[$result['tag']]['percent']['count_4_stars'] = $result['count_4_stars'];
  }
}

function MYMODULE_votingapi_metadata_alter(&$data) {
  $data['functions']['count_4_stars'] = array(
    'name' => t('4 stars'),
    'description' => t('4 stars'),
    'module' => 'mymodule',
  );
}
```

Do you know from where comes the problem?

Comment: Hello! What did you mean by 'did not work'? Were you getting incorrect results or did it not display correctly?

Comment: I find the option "4 stars" in views, but the result is always 0